# Regular expression:parse namespaces in c# source code

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I wanna parse namespaces in c# cs file, for example `using System.Collections.Generic` I want to capture groups (`System`) (`Collections`) (`Generic`).

So far i wrote this regular expression: `"[ .]?(\w*?)(?=[.;])"`

but it also marks every words which suits this pattern.
[image: picture with result]

So I have to add condition that line begins with "`using`".

I tried to add this `"using[ .]?(\w*?)(?=[.;])"` but it will only capture first namespace.

[image: picture with result]

There is input text

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string someString;
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Update:**

I'm sorry I didn't mentioned it first, but there is one more thing, the same thing will happen with Methods, for example, `Console.ReadLine()` shouldnt return `ReadLine`. The same for all dots that are not in using

Comment: Can't you use two regexes? Or not using regex at all?

Comment: using regex is obligatory.

Comment: What about using 2 regexes? One for getting everything after `using`, then another for getting the subnamespaces.

Comment: No.I need to write it in one regex

Comment: And which flavour of regex?

Comment: it's PCRE(PHP) greedy

Comment: Try [`(?m)^using +|\G(?!^)(\w+)[.;]`](https://regex101.com/r/Ndvac2/1)

Comment: try /using ((\w+\.)*\w+);/

Answer (score 2):

To start to match repeating patterns from a specific point you will find `\G` token helpful:

```
(?m)(?:^using +|\G(?!^)\.)\K\w+
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/e4UMuC/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `(?m)` Enable multiline mode
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `^using +` Match `using` at start of line following spaces
- `|` Or

  - `\G(?!^)` Start match from where previous match ended
  - `\.` Match a period
- `)` End of non-capturing group
- `\K` Reset output
- `\w+` Match a sequence of word characters

Comment: Super nice answer, I didn't know `\G` and `\K`. So powerful, I will I could vote more than one time. By the way, wouldn't `(?m)(?:^using +|\G\.)\K\w+` work fine as well?

Comment: Thank you. No, omitting lookahead will cause engine to match `.someString` at the very beginning of input string. See here https://regex101.com/r/feOUrE/1

Comment: I see didn't take into account this possibility! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this `(using |[.])(\w+)`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/LHBjNo/4)

Comment: It potentially takes much more. Look here https://regex101.com/r/LHBjNo/5

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** The following regex

```
(?<=using\s)(\w*(?=[.;]))|\G(\w*(?=[;.]))
```

will give you result as below

`(?<=using\s)`  Positive Lookbehind `using` and `\s` whitespace

`(\w*(?=[.;]))` matches any word character befor `.` or `;`

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match.

`(\w+(?=[.;]))` repeat matches any word character befor `.` or `;`

[Check demo here](https://regex101.com/r/4xRMtq/4)

Comment: Yeah, i add this note to my question

Comment: @A.Ryshkov Updated

Comment: @revo Thanks, Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex:

```
(?<=^using\s)((?:\w+)(?:[.](?:\w+))*)(?=;)
```

**input:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string something;
abc.something;
Console.WriteLine(".test.');
```

**matches:**

```
System
System.Collections.Generic
System.Linq
System.Text
System.IO
System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

then use the function on each match to extract each intermediate module:

```
$submodules= explode(".", $match);
```

**demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/p0K3dN/4/

**Code sample:**

```
$input="

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string something;
abc.something;
Console.WriteLine('.test.');

";

preg_match_all('/(?<=using\s)(?:\w+)(?:[.](?:\w+))*(?=;)/m', $input, $matches);

foreach($matches as $modules)
    foreach($modules as $module)
            print_r(explode(".",$module));
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => System
)
Array
(
    [0] => System
    [1] => Collections
    [2] => Generic
)
Array
(
    [0] => System
    [1] => Linq
)
Array
(
    [0] => System
    [1] => Text
)
Array
(
    [0] => System
    [1] => IO
)
Array
(
    [0] => System
    [1] => Text
    [2] => RegularExpressions
)
```

Comment: This is the same as @MJNBelief's answer.

Comment: @revo: Nice pick, I have answered to this question way too quickly.
I have edited my answer now.

Comment: It's not working
using System.Collections.Generic;
doesn't capture Collections

Comment: I'm sorry, but i need namespaces to be already captured in regular expression, you just get all namespaces in one group